# Can't get post_updated hook to work

Tags: posts, hooks

I am trying to add some code to be run when a post is updated. To get started I have added the following code to my functions.php:

```
function check_values($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){
    echo 'Post ID:';
    var_dump($post_ID);

    echo 'Post Object AFTER update:';
    var_dump($post_after);

    echo 'Post Object BEFORE update:';
    var_dump($post_before);
}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 );
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Nothing has changed when updating a post - nothing is echoed or dumped on screen.

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I guess it is supposed to show the echoes and var_dumps on screen as I update a post? It doesnt do that :-)

Comment: Try writing logs. Sometimes due to the theme or any other reason data won't echo using var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work you can try to use a `wp_insert_post` action:

```
function insert_post_hook($post_id, $post) {

    if ($post->post_date != $post->post_modified) {
        // This post is being updated!
    }
    else {
        // This post is being created!
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'insert_post_hook', 10, 2 );
```

If you want to see the latest version you could enable revisions:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );
```

This will save a maximum of 3 revisions.

After enabling you can check the following:

```
$latest_revision = array_shift(wp_get_post_revisions($post->ID));
```

Comment: What I need to do, is to compare the old content of the post with the new content. I am adding notifications for things that has changed. That's why I wanted to use post_updated with $post_before. Can I do something similar with wp_insert_post?

Comment: I think this can only be done with revisions, see modified answer.

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't the following approach echo on screen when saving a post? It doesn't do that either.. function insert_post_hook($post_id, $post) {
 echo 'The post was saved';
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'insert_post_hook', 10, 2 );

Comment: You should probably add a `exit;` afterwards.

Comment: Okay. I managed to get my post_revisions. However, the $latest_revision only contains the title, time and some more basic stuff. It doesnt contain all the fields that are shown in revisions in the editor. Can I get it all somehow?

Comment: I assume you are doing this locally. As such, use a GUI for MySQL like http://www.sequelpro.com/